# Running Firefox using selenium in Eclipse

Tags: selenium, eclipse

I am unable to run firefox test using selenium. It opens FF but didnt perform the action. Below are the info

```
Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
 Firefox\browser\features\aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi
1492260119271   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi
1492260119276   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on aushelper@mozilla.org version 2.0
1492260119277   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\deployment-checker@mozilla.org.xpi
1492260119278   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\deployment-checker@mozilla.org.xpi
1492260119283   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on deployment-checker@mozilla.org version 1.0
1492260119283   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1492260119283   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1492260119286   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.9
1492260119286   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1492260119287   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1492260119291   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.5
1492260119298   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Starting async load of XPI database C:\Users\Tutu\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous22270286133365338webdriver-profile\extensions.json
1492260119299   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
1492260119300   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
1492260119302   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on webcompat@mozilla.org version 1.0
1492260119305   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1492260119305   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1492260119305   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1492260119305   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1492260119305   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1492260119306   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1492260119313   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1492260119314   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1492260119314   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1492260119314   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1492260119314   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1492260119314   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
[GFX1]: Potential driver version mismatch ignored due to missing DLLs 0.0.0.0 and 0.0.0.0
1492260119597   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Async JSON file read took 0 MS
1492260119597   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Finished async read of XPI database, parsing...
1492260119599   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Successfully read XPI database
1492260119612   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1492260119612   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1492260119612   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
1492260119717   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1492260119717   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1492260119717   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[C0][GFX1]: Potential driver version mismatch ignored due to missing DLLs 0.0.0.0 and 0.0.0.0 (t=2.70801) [GFX1]: Potential driver version mismatch ignored due to missing DLLs 0.0.0.0 and 0.0.0.0

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
    at GoogleTest.main(GoogleTest.java:10)
Apr 15, 2017 1:42:46 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog destroyHarder
INFO: Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully (v2). org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog@77847718
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: 
 Firefox\browser\features\aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi
1492260119271   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi
1492260119276   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on aushelper@mozilla.org version 2.0
1492260119277   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\deployment-checker@mozilla.org.xpi
1492260119278   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\deployment-checker@mozilla.org.xpi
1492260119283   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on deployment-checker@mozilla.org version 1.0
1492260119283   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1492260119283   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1492260119286   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.9
1492260119286   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1492260119287   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1492260119291   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.5
1492260119298   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Starting async load of XPI database C:\Users\Tutu\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous22270286133365338webdriver-profile\extensions.json
1492260119299   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
1492260119300   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
1492260119302   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on webcompat@mozilla.org version 1.0
1492260119305   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1492260119305   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1492260119305   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1492260119305   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1492260119305   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1492260119306   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1492260119313   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1492260119314   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1492260119314   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1492260119314   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1492260119314   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1492260119314   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
[GFX1]: Potential driver version mismatch ignored due to missing DLLs 0.0.0.0 and 0.0.0.0
1492260119597   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Async JSON file read took 0 MS
1492260119597   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Finished async read of XPI database, parsing...
1492260119599   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Successfully read XPI database
1492260119612   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1492260119612   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1492260119612   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
1492260119717   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1492260119717   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1492260119717   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[C0][GFX1]: Potential driver version mismatch ignored due to missing DLLs 0.0.0.0 and 0.0.0.0 (t=2.70801) [GFX1]: Potential driver version mismatch ignored due to missing DLLs 0.0.0.0 and 0.0.0.0

Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '32a636c', time: '2015-03-05 22:01:35'
System info: host: 'Tutu-Lounge', ip: '192.168.173.2', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
    at GoogleTest.main(GoogleTest.java:10)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
 Firefox\browser\features\aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi
1492260119271   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi
1492260119276   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on aushelper@mozilla.org version 2.0
1492260119277   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\deployment-checker@mozilla.org.xpi
1492260119278   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\deployment-checker@mozilla.org.xpi
1492260119283   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on deployment-checker@mozilla.org version 1.0
1492260119283   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1492260119283   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1492260119286   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.9
1492260119286   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1492260119287   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1492260119291   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.5
1492260119298   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Starting async load of XPI database C:\Users\Tutu\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous22270286133365338webdriver-profile\extensions.json
1492260119299   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
1492260119300   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
1492260119302   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on webcompat@mozilla.org version 1.0
1492260119305   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1492260119305   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1492260119305   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1492260119305   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1492260119305   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1492260119306   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1492260119313   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1492260119314   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1492260119314   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1492260119314   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1492260119314   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1492260119314   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
[GFX1]: Potential driver version mismatch ignored due to missing DLLs 0.0.0.0 and 0.0.0.0
1492260119597   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Async JSON file read took 0 MS
1492260119597   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Finished async read of XPI database, parsing...
1492260119599   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Successfully read XPI database
1492260119612   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1492260119612   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1492260119612   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
1492260119717   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1492260119717   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1492260119717   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[C0][GFX1]: Potential driver version mismatch ignored due to missing DLLs 0.0.0.0 and 0.0.0.0 (t=2.70801) [GFX1]: Potential driver version mismatch ignored due to missing DLLs 0.0.0.0 and 0.0.0.0

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: When you ask for help with a programming problem, it helps to provide a minimal example that demonstrates the problem: minimal because it helps narrow down the problem.  Please consider doing that for the question you asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Try Upgrading your graphics drivers.  Also your firefox version to be the latest.  You may need version 53 (beta)

For more information see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1242659

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firefox with the version like 42 or 43 (find and download them all from here: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/) if there is no hard and fast rule to use updated Firefox browser. 
If you have one installed with the version more than 43, uninstall that first and install the downloaded one.

Answer (score 0):

****Experimental Workaround, no guarantee for anything*****

I got it running with the up to date Firefox but it's a little bit of a hassle and makes your selenium node cry out.

1. Download current Selenium and GeckoDriver, set paths, configure Buildpaths, the whole standard thing.
2. Add Desired Capabilities if you don't have them already and add the argument `.setCapability("marionette", false);`
3. Start your Hub as `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar -port [Any free Port]` just don't use the default 4444.
4. Start a Node as `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar -role node -hub http://127.0.0.1:[your Port]/wd/register -enablePassThrough true`
5. Your node should now output `INFO - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 12 path $` don't worry, it will still work thanks to enablePassThrough

Now you should be able to use Firefox >= 47. This circumvents anything the W3C recommends for WebDrivers (this is why the node is crying) but it works. Good luck and ask if anything doesn't work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Download latest Firefox or gecko driver from http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Seleniumgecko\\geckodriver.exe);
```

Comment: Please edit this answer to explain how it would solve the OP's problem.